# TelerikGrid async datasource

Tags: c#, async-await, telerik-grid

I'm trying to set data of grid by fetching data asynchronously from DB but it is not working. Probably I'm missing something.

```
@page "/Test"
@using System.Dynamic;

<div class="col-md-12">
    <TelerikButton OnClick="ButtonClick">Click Me to see data</TelerikButton>
    <TelerikGrid Class="grid"
                 Data=@GridFilter
                 Sortable="true"
                 FilterMode="GridFilterMode.FilterMenu"
                 Resizable="true"
                 SelectionMode="GridSelectionMode.Multiple"
                 Pageable="true"
                 PageSize=20
                 Navigable="true">

        <GridColumns>
            <GridColumn Field="Field1" Title="Field1" />
            <GridColumn Field="Field2" Width="300px" Title="Field2" TextAlign="@ColumnTextAlign.Center" />
        </GridColumns>
    </TelerikGrid>
</div>

}
@code {
    private List<dynamic> GridFilter;

    private async Task ButtonClick()
    {
        GridFilter = await this.GetData();
    }

    private async Task<List<dynamic>> GetData()
    {
        Task<List<dynamic>> b = new(() => {
            dynamic A = new ExpandoObject();
            A.Field1 = "Field 1";
            A.Field2 = "Field 2";
            List<dynamic> grid = new();
            grid.Add(A);
            return grid;
        });
        return await b;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/grid/refresh-data#observable-data), if you want the grid to automatically update when you update the list, you have to declare the collection as an [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1). You'll likely also have to initialize an empty collection so that the grid can subscribe to its events:

```
private ObservableCollection<dynamic> GridFilter = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>();
```

But that means you cannot replace `GridFilter` with a new instance of a collection, like you're doing here:

```
GridFilter = await this.GetData();
```

You'll have to add each item to the existing collection. You can either do that in your `ButtonClick()` event, or add the items directly to `GridFilter` in `GetData()`.

`ObservableCollection` doesn't support `AddRange()` unfortunately, so you'll have to add one at a time. Or, you can use this [`ObservableRangeCollection`](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers/blob/master/MvvmHelpers/ObservableRangeCollection.cs) class someone wrote to make it support `AddRange`.

The other way is to call the [Rebind method](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/grid/refresh-data#rebind-method) on the grid after you change the collection, which might look something like this (untested, so it might need some tweaks):

```
    <TelerikGrid Class="grid"
                 Data=@GridFilter
                 Sortable="true"
                 FilterMode="GridFilterMode.FilterMenu"
                 Resizable="true"
                 SelectionMode="GridSelectionMode.Multiple"
                 Pageable="true"
                 PageSize=20
                 Navigable="true"
                 @ref="@GridRef">
```

```
    private async Task ButtonClick()
    {
        GridFilter = await this.GetData();
        GridRef.Rebind();
    }
```